# How does a sender computer knows the port number of a custom process on receiver computer?

Tags: networking, tcp, ip

How does TCP segment knows what port number the segment needs to be sent to.

Comment: Because that's what the socket is connected to.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, then things are very simple. The port number of the recipient as well as the port number of the sending host are written as part of the TCP header at the very beginning. Have you ever seen a TCP header before? Take a look at the following picture. The first thing that any TCP header begins with are the source and destination ports of the sending and receiving sides.

[image]

If what you are asking is how does the destination port number get there in the first place, then the answer to that question is that the sending host places it there. What that means is that the sending host must know in advance what port the receiving process is listening on. For example, in the case of the Web, your browser knows that all web servers that use nonsecure HTTP listen on port 80. So, it automatically fills in the destination port field with a value of 80. And that's roughly what goes on behind the scenes, so to speak.